# In haproxy, what’t the ACL rule to check whether a server is up and running or not?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

In the file `/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg`, How can we determine if a server is running or shutdown to be used in some conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you medan something like the `check` parameter in each `server` definition? It can be complemented with more advanced `http-check` or `tcp-check` definitions.  See the manual for more in-depth descriptions.

Comment: you mean something like this: `acl name http-check <IP>` ?

Comment: No, something like `server server1 <IP>:<PORT> check`; possibly preceded by `option http-check [<method>][<uri>][<version>]` or `http-check expect [!] <match> <pattern>`. (https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/aloha/10-0/traffic-management/lb-layer7/health-checks/#check-an-http-service)

Comment: I mean using acl to be able to use a condition! checking if the server is alive, then doing something else by a condition: `play a song if { server alive }`